# Show all data in postgresql table - Heroku, JackDB

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku

I am making a flask app with a postgres db on Heroku. I am using JackDB as a gui.

What postgresql query do I use to show all the stored data in my table?

When I run `select * from user` I get (sorry I can't post screenshots because of low rep):

```
id | current_user

1  | gmuchqmskrcijv
```

And when I run `select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'user'` I get:

```
id | column_name | data_type    | character_maximum_length

1  | id          | integer      | NULL

2  | email       | character v..| 120
```

I just want to list all `ids` and `emails` stored in the table 'user'.

Comment: `SELECT id,email FROM user;`

Comment: @wildplasser, I get this error when running that query: PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" does not exist

Comment: Well, your first query `select * from user` resulted in `id | current_user` as the result, so there must be an ID somewhere... Maybe you are in a different schema or database?

Answer (score 2):

To query a table named `user` you'll need to double quote it: `SELECT * FROM "user"`

`USER` is a [reserved word in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-info.html). It's a [system information function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-info.html) that returns the name of the user executing the query.

As a built-in function, it's special in that you do not specify parentheses when invoking it. Additionally, it's an alias for `CURRENT_USER` which is why when you run `SELECT * FROM user` (*without quoting it*) you get a column named `current_user` returned.

If possible, you should not use reserved words as table or column names as otherwise you'll have to quote them in all SQL that references them.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation points to up vote this, but this was the correct answer. Thank you for your response and explanation!

Comment: @SunnyMalotrha if this a correct answer, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select id,email from user;
```

or

```
select u.id,u.email from user u;
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it a little by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?